# A python GUI with a large example library application for windows

Tags: python, user-interface

A while ago I experimented with a GUI for python in windows.  It had a really big pre-installed library with all kinds of examples (trees, sliders, tabs,...) where you could play with the code to see the result and reset it when you were ready.

It's been a while since I played with it and am now on a new PC. Any idea which GUI it was?

I just installed wxpython, but I don't seem to find the example library...

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.wxpython.org/ or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29 ?

Comment: you need to download the wxpython demo seperately ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley : indeed... I better go to bed early tonight..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was probably [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/index.php), which has a pretty impressive demo.